# How to make other computers connected to my workgroup able to browse my web server via my private local domain www.mydomain.local?

Tags: iis, web-server, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, workgroup

### Background

I have a broadband connection. The fiber optic cable running from outside to my building is connected to a converter unit. The output of the converter is connected to a router. The router also provides 8 LAN ports to which the computers are connected.

Shortly speaking, all computers are interconnected in a workgroup as opposed to a domain.

My computer hosts an IIS web server using a private or local domain name `www.mydomain.local`.
I has added `127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.local` to the `hosts` file in the server `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` so I can browse the site from within the server. So far so good.

How to make other computers connected to my workgroup able to browse my web server via my private local domain `www.mydomain.local`?

Note: Again, I am a newbie. I have no idea what I should do next.

Answer (score 2):

They have to do the exact same thing you did to your hosts file, but instead of putting in "**127.0.0.1**" (which effectively means "this computer") they need to put in whatever IP your computer is actually assigned.

So if your computers real IP is "**10.53.9.16**" then they have to put

> 10.53.9.16 www.mydomain.local

into their local hosts file.

If you are on DHCP and your IP changes, they will need to update their hosts file every time it happens. Alternatively you could set up some sort of custom DNS scenario, but as a newbie that is impractical.

Another option is using Dynamic DNS - try looking into **dyndns.com** .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using DDNS might not suit my need because it expose my local site the internet, right? How to setup DNS using my server? I cannot vote up your answer now. I will do later. Not enough reputation to do so now.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options
add the info to the hosts file on each workstation, like Neobyte stated

Install your own dns server.

**IF** your website is on  true windows server software it should have a microsoft dns server available.

**IF** you are using a workstation as a server there are many free or inexpensive windows based dns servers available for download and use. Most have good documentation.

Either way, you will need to then point your other computers at it for dns service and let it go upstream to resolve other dns addresses